# Stuck colored filled area in bar chart, python

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

everyone,

I want to create a bar chart but with a filled background.

For example: 
for 0 to 1 in y axis the background must be black
for >1 to <2 in y axis the background must be red.

In other words, i want to create bar plot  with background different colored categories in yy axis

(i sorry, my rep points dont allow me to upload a pic)
Ty

**It might be closed but i think someone will find this useful: Horizontal Colored Areas**

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.axhspan(0, 1, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color ='b',linewidth = True,label ="Category 1")
plt.axhspan(0, -0.8, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color ='yellow',linewidth = True,label ="Category 2")
plt.axhspan(-0.8, -1.3, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color ='orange',linewidth = True,label ="Category 3")
plt.axhspan(-1.3, -1.6, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color = 'orangered',linewidth = True,label ="Category 4")
plt.axhspan(-1.6, -2, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color ='red',linewidth = True,label ="Category 5")
plt.axhspan(-2, -3, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5,color ='maroon',linewidth = True,label ="Category 6")
plt.xlabel("Categories")
plt.ylabel("Units")
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=False, shadow=False, ncol=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I'm fairly certain `matplotlib` has several tutorials on this.

Comment: Shashank Gupta, plz provide any link. zero323, iam think to use mathematical equations of rectangle and use plt.fill but think it must be an easier way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.bar([0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], color='b', align='center')
ax.axvspan(0, 1, color='k', alpha=.75, zorder=-1)
ax.axvspan(1, 2, color='r', alpha=.75, zorder=-1)
ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
ax.set_xlabel('fake x')
ax.set_ylabel('fake y')
```

[image]